# Legitimate Xpath queries generated by browser add-ons not working against urllib2-fetched page

Tags: python, html, xpath, lxml, urllib2

I'm looking to extract each Instruction ID from [this](https://secure.ssa.gov/apps10/reference.nsf/instructiontypecode!openview&restricttocategory=POMT) page:

[image]

```
import lxml.html as lh
url ='https://secure.ssa.gov/apps10/reference.nsf/instructiontypecode!openview&restricttocategory=POMT'
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
content = response.read()
root = lh.fromstring(content)
all_instruction_ids = root.xpath(XPATH_ALL_INSTRUCTION_IDS)
```

I've tried countless XPath expressions given to me by Chrome & Firebug's developer tools, Firebug, and other browser add-ons:

```
XPATH_ALL_INSTRUCTION_IDS = '//*[@id="content"]/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/font/a/.'
#XPATH_ALL_INSTRUCTION_IDS = '//*[@id="content"]/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/font/a/text()'
XPATH_ALL_INSTRUCTION_IDS  = '//*[@id="content"]/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/font/a[contains(normalize-space(), "")]'
XPATH_ALL_INSTRUCTION_IDS = '//*[@id="content"]/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/font/a'
XPATH_ALL_INSTRUCTION_IDS = ".//*[@id='content']/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/font/a"
XPATH_ALL_INSTRUCTION_IDS  = "//form/div[1]/div[5]/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/font/a"
XPATH_ALL_INSTRUCTION_IDS  = "id('content')/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/font/a"
XPATH_ALL_INSTRUCTION_IDS  = "/html/body/form/div[1]/div[5]/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/font/a"
XPATH_ALL_INSTRUCTION_IDS = "//html//body/form/div[1]/div[5]/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]//a"
XPATH_ALL_INSTRUCTION_IDS = "//html//body/form/div[1]/div[5]/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/*/a"
```

Yet none of them work when passed to the `xpath()` method of `lxml.html.fromstring()`

Comment: On closer inspection, the image is also present in the live source (it's just not displayed), so it must be something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would find all links containing the `reference.nsf/links` inside an `href`:

```
//table//a[contains(@href, 'reference.nsf/links')]/text()
```

Works for me.

Comment: Nice. If the path pointed to by the hrefs every changes, this would break, but then the same could be same about the robustness or lack thereof of other working queries.

Comment: @Pyderman well, I've just spotted this `reference.nsf/links` common part in the hrefs. I don't think this is less reliable than `//font/a` - the `font` tag itself is a poor choice to be used inside locators since it is style/ui/design specific, not data-oriented.

Comment: @Pyderman note that we can even use `//table//a/text()` in this case, since all of the links in the table are instruction ids..

Comment: True enough. By the same token, would you expand the query to `//table//a[contains(@href, 'reference.nsf/links')][contains(normalize-space(), '')]` to allow for potentially other tags before the text of the anchor?

Comment: @Pyderman not sure, have not seen this trick before. Could you provide an example when it might be useful? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `//` xpath operator does not require you to start from the top of the document.

```
XPATH_ALL_INSTRUCTION_IDS = '//font/a'
```

I recommend you look into an [xpath cheatsheet](http://xpath.alephzarro.com/content/cheatsheet.html).

Comment: True, and in the end, I am using `//tr/td[1]/font/a/.` But it's a brittle query, and one that could break easily. This is the first time I've encountered a page element that doesn't get picked up by a fully-formed query right back to the root. And I'm baffled as to why these legitimate queries generated in the browser are not working on the page source as seen by urllib2.